# How to handle variables inside of try/catch error handling?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I want to assing thumbnails of videos to uiimageviews by reading the videos names and create a thumbnail based on these names.

Here is my code:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    // We need just to get the documents folder url
    let documentsUrl = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as NSURL

    do { let directoryUrls = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsSubdirectoryDescendants)
    } catch {
        let directoryUrls = documentsUrl
    }

    let video = AVAsset(URL: directoryUrls)
    let AVThumbnailAsset = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: video)
    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 1)
    var actualTime : CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)
    let myImage: CGImage
    let convertedImage: UIImage

    do{
        myImage = try AVThumbnailAsset.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: &actualTime)
        convertedImage = UIImage.init(CGImage: myImage)

    } catch {
        print("This is the Error")
        print(error)
        convertedImage = UIImage(named: "2.35:1")!
    }


  videoThumb.image = convertedImage
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At first I can see is that you are trying to  useSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants and it is not allowed. Options for the enumeration. Because this method performs only shallow enumerations, options that prevent descending into subdirectories or packages are not allowed; the only supported option is NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles.

Comment: You are passing an array of urls instead o a single video url

Comment: } catch let error as NSError { print(error.localizedDescription) }

Comment: okay even with your edits, the error still remains:

Use of unresolved identifier 'directoryUrls'

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: move your code inside do { after let directoryUrls = try NSFileManager.

Comment: Got it working.. Forgot to put in indexPath.row

But my collectionView still looks terrible.. All the pictures are resizing if i scroll through them.. It looks totally random?!